# MacBook Pro fans loudly when disk is being used

Tags: mac, fan

My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) fans extremely loudly when a large amount of disk operations are happening (such as downloading something). Although the computer is usually hot near the top of the keyboard where the screen is near, it does not fan unless the disk is being used.

Comment: its a macbook, so if you are having a hardware problem, you are probably best off having it professionally serviced.

Comment: what is your question? ... `fans are noisy` is not a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have described, you do not have a problem.

Yes, disk is being used, and so are other components, and that load is generating heat, and the fans spin to make that heat go away.

Based on what you have said, there is no problem here.